# How service do its work even if its component destroyed?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

from [AndoridDeveloper documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> a service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed.

also

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise).

how service continue its work even if its app destroyed ?

in this question i assumed :

**component mean app** .

**app Process destroyed when app destroyed** .

if(any of those assumptions is wrong){
why is wrong ?
}else {please answer the question}

Comment: Because Service is independent of its component i.e Activity, Broadcast Receiver, Service etc

Comment: that mean service and app component are part of main thread ?

Comment: `that mean service and app component are part of main thread ?` Yes, they are running in the main thread of their hosting process!

Comment: what does hosting process here mean ?

Comment: `Hosting Process` is the application process in which the components like Activity, Service exists!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say anything about the application being destroyed, your characterization is not correct.

It says:

> A service is "started" when an application component (such as an
>   activity) starts it by calling startService(). Once started, a service
>   can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that
>   started it is destroyed.

This merely means that a Service can continue running even after a component such as an Activity or another Service in your app that started it with a call to `startService()` is destroyed.

If your app's process is terminated, then all components running in the process including all Services are ended (assuming none of them have been declared to run in their own process):

> Android might decide to shut down a process at some point, when memory
>   is low and required by other processes that are more immediately
>   serving the user. Application components running in the process that's
>   killed are consequently destroyed. A process is started again for
>   those components when there's again work for them to do.